# Java cannot resolve method "size()"

Tags: java, methods

I'm not a regular java user, but I need to get the number of elements in a list in Java. I'm trying to use the size method, but it's not resolving as expected.

List and Arraylist are imported into the file as expected.

Code:

```
Optional<List<ColleagueDevice>> storeDevices = releaseService.storeDevices(storeNumber);
int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.size();
if (numberOfDevices == 5) {
    log.error("Failed to release device for colleague: {} in store {} as 5 devices are already released", body.getColleagueId(), storeNumber);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            //TODO: check ALREADY_HAS_DEVICE
            new UIStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), ALREADY_HAS_DEVICE),
            HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED
    );
}
```

Comment: @Shark `storeDevices.get()` will _never_ return null.

Comment: @Shark You missed the question mark for ternary operator. Please edit before its gone.

Comment: Since it's an `Optional` holding a `List<Something>`, why not do something like this instead?
`numberOfDevices =  (storeDevices.isPresent()) ? storeDevices.get().size() : -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have received an `Optional<List<ColleagueDevice>>`, not a `List<ColleagueDevice>`, so you cannot invoke `size()`, because [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) has no such method (and if it had, it would probably not return the list size).

You need to extract the value from the `Optional`, taking into account that the optional might be empty (doesn't contain a list):

#### Supply a default list if empty

```java
int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList).size();
```

or

```java
int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.orElse(Collections.emptyList()).size();
```

#### Conditionally get the size or use a default value

```java
int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.isPresent() ? storeDevices.get().size() : 0;
```

or

```java
int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.map(List::size).orElse(0);
```

This last option has a bit more overhead due to boxing and unboxing of integers, but might be simpler to read.

As an aside, the fact this API returns `Optional<List<ColleagueDevice>>` is in my opinion a bit odd. The more natural API would be `List<ColleagueDevice>` where an empty list is used when there are no results.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. 
I'm working to build upon an existing solution first built by someone who was learning Java while writing this, and who has since left the company. I didn't realise the Optional class was what I was really trying to invoke a method on.

Answer (score 2):

It is an `Optional<T>` object, that can be either present or absent.

```java
storeDevices.get().size();
```

would first attempt to fetch the object (if present), and then call `.size()` on it; however, beware, that `.get()` might throw `NoSuchElementException`, if object in question is absent.

See [Optional API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) for more details. Methods, like [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)), [`orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.Supplier)), [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) are also present there.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an Optional list, you must first get the items before calling size() on the list. `int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.get().size();`

Comment: If the `Optional` is empty, calling `get()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: You can have a default empty list if the Optional is empty.
 `int numberOfDevices = storeDevices.orElse(Collections.emptyList()).size();`